# Add image in streaming mode with exceljs

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, node-modules, exceljs

I'm developing a reporting system. In study the exceljs library I verified that the streaming mode due to the volume of data, and in the tests it would suit me and it really suited me perfectly.

However, I have a problem, it does not let you add an image to the worksheet. returning the worksheet.addImage error is not function.
Does anyone know how I can get around this?

Comment: The maintainers of the project keep pushing it aside and it just something that someone would need ot fix by themselves and PR it to the project.